# Commenting on audit tests - review queues

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I was reviewing [first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/) and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28087207) and decided to leave a comment. After I had pressed "post comment" it told me that I was reviewing the question incorrectly even though my comment wasn't necessarily a review.

Comment: What comment did you think needed to be posted there?